# Redux array is sometimes empty

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

My app stores objects (movies) in an array (movieList) in localStorage by using the localForage package.  I have a component that renders the objects (movies) in the movieList array. I use Redux to manage my data/state. I can add movies and display the movies on my `movieOverview` component:

App.tsx

```
localforage.getItem<IMovie []>('trackedMovies').then((trackedMovies) => {
  if (!trackedMovies) {
    localforage.setItem('trackedMovies', []);
  } else {
    console.log('shows array, not promise', trackedMovies);
    dispatch((initialLoad(trackedMovies)));
  }
});
```

action:

```
export const initialLoad = (movieList) => {
  console.log('shows array, not promise', movieList);
  return {
    type: 'initialLoad',
    payLoad: movieList,
  };
};
```

reducer:

```
const movieListReducer = (state = [{}], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'addMovieToStore':
      return [...state, action.payLoad];
    case 'initialLoad':
      console.log(action.payLoad);
      return action.payLoad;
    default:
      return [];
  }
};

export default movieListReducer;
```

movieOverview:

```
const movieList = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.movieList);

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    console.log(movieList.length);
  });
}, [movieList]);
```

I'm using a `window.addEventListener('resize', () => {});` in my component and when I resize the screen the `console.log(movieList.length);` outputs:

> 0

> 1

Can anyone explain why the `movieList` array is empty when I resize the viewport?

Comment: I suspect that it has something to do with register the resize event each time movieList array is updated, or not having a removeEventListener in the hook. Also, you only need to register the resize event at initial load of movieOverview, so you should have an empty array in the hook.

Comment: The array is there because I want to update the view when the movieList array is changed. So it reacts when movieList is updated. I had a removeEventLister but that didn't make a difference, but I should put it back either way.

Comment: Yes, you should have unsub from the eventListener in any case - you don't want to have memory leaks issues. Where and how is the LocalStorage call invoked?

Comment: Issue is resolved. It was indeed unsubbing the event listener and putting the code issue the event listener into a function. On the unsub remove the function and voila.

Comment: Great! Good to know

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is some other action that is not `addMovieToStore` or `initialLoad` is being dispatched and the default case in your `movieListReducer` is being returned, which is an empty array.

I would try making your default case return `state` and see if that fixes things, and for good measure, use the spread operator on the `initialLoad` case.

```js
const movieListReducer = (state = [{}], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'addMovieToStore':
      return [...state, action.payLoad];
    case 'initialLoad':
      console.log(action.payLoad);
      return [...action.payLoad];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default movieListReducer;
```

Comment: I thought the same but I've put logs in each case but nothing is logged. There's also no reference to any Redux action. Maybe the component is rerendered when the viewport changes causing some strange behavior?